# How to find which items in list of lists is equal to another list

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
[[0],
[0, 1, 2],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[7],
[8],
[9],
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[11],
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[13],
[14],
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[16, 17, 18],
[17],
[17, 18]]
```

I am trying to find the least number of items in the list, when concatenated, that equal the full range of the list. In this case, the full range of the list is this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

So in this case, these two items from the list of lists would equal the full range:

```
[0]
[0, 1, 2]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
---> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[7]
[8]
[9]
---> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[11]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[13]
[14]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[16, 17, 18]
[17]
[17, 18]
```

Comment: It is not clear what your last example represents. Could you please explain more what is your expected output? is it the `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]`?

Comment: The expected output should be `[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]]`

Answer (score 1):

One way using `itertools.permutations` and `chain`:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

starget = sorted(target)
for i in range(2, len(target)):
    for perm in permutations(l, i):
        if sorted(chain(*perm)) == starget:
            print(i, perm)
            break
    break
```

Output:

```
2 ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand, how does this work? What is `target`?