# How to find the least number of items in list that add to total value

Tags: python, list, numpy, tree, sum

I have a list of n number of unique values. In this case, there are 19 values stored in variable `total`. It looks like this:

```
total = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

The items in total relate to each other in varying ways. In this example, the dependencies between items is structured like this:

```
tree = [
[0],
[0, 1, 2],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[7],
[8],
[9],
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[11],
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[13],
[14],
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[16, 17, 18],
[17],
[17, 18]
]
```

I want to find the least number of items in `tree` that are equal to `total`. In this example, the least number of items from `tree` that equal `total` would be:

```
tree = [
[0],
[0, 1, 2],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
---> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[7],
[8],
[9],
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[11],
---> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[13],
[14],
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[16, 17, 18],
[17],
[17, 18]
]
```

So it would select the 6th and 10th items from the list.
However, in the event that `tree` had a different structure and looked like this:

```
tree = [
[0],
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5],
[6],
[7],
[8],
[9],
[10],
[11],
[12],
[13],
[14],
[15],
[16],
[17],
[18]
]
```

I would want all items of the list selected.

One approach I was thinking would be finding the least number of items in `total` that equal, when summed, to the sum of `total`. In this case, the sum of `total` is 171, so how do I find the least amount of items in `tree` that when summed, equal 171?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765897/how-to-find-which-items-in-list-of-lists-is-equal-to-another-list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find total value

```
  f = 0
  for i in total:
      f += i
```

Sort your tree (high to low).

```
  def some_sorting_algoritm(tree):
      ...
      return sorted_array
```

Simplify your branches, so your tree array only shows the total values of each branch (you are only using the totals):

and then loop through your new list from high to low to see if you have any matches. Here you will have to provide some logic.

*Note: sometimes the branch of the tree will have a higher number than total, so take that in consideration when you write your logic.*